# powershell, change -WhatIf message text color

Tags: powershell

it's easy to change error, warning, debug, verbose, progress messages aspect by changing the value of the corresponding `$host.PrivateData.<MessageType>ForegroundColor` or `$host.PrivateData.<MessageType>BackgroundColor`, but I found no way to change the color of `-WhatIf` messages to anything other than the bland gray, in order to make it more visible.

did I miss something or is it just impossible?

#### Update 1

according to the info in the github thread quoted by @zett42, the `-whatif` messages are displayed by a simple `CBhost.UI.WriteLine(whatIfMessage)` and so, are not subject to coloring

Comment: It's not possible to capture or redirect `-WhatIf` so this is likely not possible

Comment: nevermind my prev. comment, it is possible but  you definitely do not want to do it

Comment: You might want to upvote https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/9870

Comment: Ditto to what '@ Santiago Squarzon' said, yet, what you are comparing for the change is not apples to apples. As we all know, ```error, warning, debug, verbose, progress``` are all ```Write-*``` family cmdlets, and ```-What-If``` is a switch allowed by properties in such cmdlets. I too am an accessibility type, due to orgs/ents I've had and still do support. Yet, when it comes to colors, those who can't see them at all or who have color blindness with regards to some colors, is a different conversation. So, us making decisions on such things cannot do so in a vacuum.

Answer (score 0):

Since `-WhatIf` cannot be captured or redirected the only possible solution I see, which **I do not advocate**, is to inject [VT sequences](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/console-virtual-terminal-sequences) **before reaching [`$PSCmdlet.ShouldProcess`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/learn/deep-dives/everything-about-shouldprocess?view=powershell-7.3)**. Sharing this for the sake of learning but please do not consider it robust.

```
0..10 | & {
    [CmdletBinding(SupportsShouldProcess)]
    param([Parameter(ValueFromPipeline)] [string] $Test)

    process {
        # if using WhatIf
        if($PSBoundParameters.ContainsKey('WhatIf')) {
            # inject VT sequence for bright yellow
            $Host.UI.Write("$([char] 27)[93m")
        }
        if($PSCmdlet.ShouldProcess($Test, 'waving')) {
            "hello $Test"
        }
        # inject VT sequence for Reset console color
        $Host.UI.Write("$([char] 27)[0m")
    }
} -WhatIf
```

Updating the [`ForegroundColor` Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.host.pshostrawuserinterface.foregroundcolor?view=powershellsdk-7.3.0#system-management-automation-host-pshostrawuserinterface-foregroundcolor) would also be an option, either way this needs to be done prior the call to `$PSCmdlet.ShouldProcess(...)`:

```
$Host.UI.RawUI.ForegroundColor = [ConsoleColor]::Yellow
```

Comment: I don't think I will do that :-) but should I be tempted by the dark side of the code, I'd rather use ```$host.ui.rawui.foregroundcolor = 'yellow'``` instead of VT sequence

Comment: @Peyre yep that's another option

Answer (score 0):

A more reserved approach I'm taking, inspired by Azure Bicep, is to use ANSI escape sequences to colorize markers that indicate the type of operation the `-WhatIf` action will perform. The new windows terminal supports them and it does help break up the monotony.

For all those cmdlets that don't support color, we can simply wrap them in our own WhatIf and emulate the message they would normally return.

```
function Color {
    [CmdletBinding(SupportsShouldProcess)]
    param(
        [switch] $NoColor
    )

    # Color
    $CreateMark = if ($NoColor -or $env:NO_COLOR) { "[+]" } else { "$([char]0x1b)[32m[+]$([char]0x1b)[37m" }
    $DeleteMark = if ($NoColor -or $env:NO_COLOR) { "[-]" } else { "$([char]0x1b)[31m[-]$([char]0x1b)[37m" }
    $ModifyMark = if ($NoColor -or $env:NO_COLOR) { "[~]" } else { "$([char]0x1b)[35m[~]$([char]0x1b)[37m" }

    if ($PSCmdlet.ShouldProcess("$CreateMark Create Foo.txt")) { New-Item Foo.txt }
    if ($PSCmdlet.ShouldProcess("$DeleteMark Remove Foo.txt")) { Remove-Item Foo.txt }
    if ($PSCmdlet.ShouldProcess("$ModifyMark Modify Foo.txt")) { Set-Content Foo.txt }
}

Color -WhatIf
```